# Prove uniqueness in division algorithm

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-explanation

I have been asked to prove the following:

> Let $n \in \Bbb{N}$. For every $m \in \Bbb{Z}$ there are unique $q,r
> > \in \Bbb{Z}$ such that $m=qn+r$ and $0 \leq r \leq n-1$.

I am mostly comfortable with proving existence, but am less so with proving uniqueness. I guess I don't really understand how to prove uniqueness for really anything.

The "proof" we are given for uniqueness goes as follows:

Suppose that

$$m=qn+r= q'n+r'.$$

Thus $(q'-q)n+r'-r=0.$

*Proof*:

We see that

$$(q'-q)n=-(r'-r) = r - r'.$$

If $r=r'$, then $q=q'$, then we are done.

Otherwise, by multiplying by $-1$, we may assume that $(r-r') \in \Bbb{N}$. But since $r-r'$ is a natural number, $q'-q$ is also a natural number. But then $(q'-q)n \geq n$. We conclude that $(r-r') \geq n$. On the other hand $r \leq n-1$, so $r-r' \leq n-1$. This is absurd. We conclude that $q=q'$ and $r=r'$, i.e., that $q$ and $r$ are unique.

Comment: What is the problem with this PROOF?

Comment: The proof is correct, I just don't understand it.

Comment: @agra94: That is rather vague. Could you be more specific? How much of it do you understand? Where do you start having trouble?

Comment: Honestly at the very beginning. Does proving uniqueness illustrate showing how the different variables are dependent on another one? In this case, it appears as though they are ultimately dependent on n. So, if n fluctuates, q and r will as well. Is this basically the gist of what we're trying to prove?

Comment: I also don't understand why this requires showing how r-r' and q'-q are natural numbers. Who cares?

Comment: @agra94: They use $r'-r$ being natural to prove that $q-q'$ must be natural, which eventually determines the direction of the inequality $(q-q')n\geq n$. Also, naturality gives a lower bound on $r'-r$ so that it cannot be a negative multiple of $n$. But I think the whole proof-by-contradiction tactic renders the proof slightly confusing. See my answer for an alternative, yet partially similar, approach.

Comment: @Sting Hmm. I guess I'm still trying to understand what the above proof is doing. What does proof by contradiction lead to us saying that results in a false statement? I see that we show first that  r-r' $\geq$ n and then that r-r' $\leq$ n-1, and I understand that this is a contradiction. Does the proof by contradiction allow us to say that r=r' because that is the only way in which r-r' $\geq$ n and then that r-r' $\leq$ n-1 can be true?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your difficulty is just a point of logic.  When we want to prove uniqueness of a thing, it's a standard technique to assume there are two different such things and then show that they are *not* different after all.

Suppose I needed to prove that there is a unique integer between 3 and 5.  I would assume that there were two such integers, $x$ and $y$ such that $3<x<5$ and $3<y<5$.  Then I would try to argue that $x=y$, and probably that argument would be "by contradiction."  That is, I would assume $x \neq y$ and try to get an absurdity.

Since one of $x$ and $y$ is bigger than the other (because we're assuming they're not equal) and since it makes no difference which one is bigger, we might as well assume (WLOG, as they say) that $x>y$.  One way to say this is $x-y$ is a natural number (because natural numbers are positive.)

Now that things are set up nicely, I can get on with my (silly) proof:
Since $3<x<5,$ we have $3-y < x-y <5-y$.  And since $y>3$, $5-y <5-3 =2$,
so $5-y\leq 1.$  Combining these inequalities gives us $x-y < 5-y \leq 1$,
so $x-y$ is a natural number less than one, absurd.  I conclude that $x-y$.

Comment: Nice (should be a standard textbook proof) for beginners to learn proof by contradiction.

Answer (score 4):

If $r\ne r'$, it's not restrictive to assume $r>r'$ (otherwise exchange their role, or repeat the argument).

Then $0<r-r'<n$. From $r-r'=q'n-qn=(q'-q)n$, we obtain
$$
0<(q'-q)n<n
$$
and, canceling $n$,
$$
0<q'-q<1
$$
which is impossible.

Answer (score 1):

Consider this.

$N=qn+r$ and $M =pn+s ;0\le r <n$ and $0\le s < n $.  We want to figure out if and when $N=M $.

Case 1: $q > p $

The $N -(q-p)n = pn+r $

$N-(q-p)n +(s-r)=pn+s = M $

So $N = M + (q-p)n +r -s$

$ \ge M+(q-p) -s $

$\ge M+1*n -s $

$=M+(n-s) \ge M +1 >M $.

So $N\ne M $

Likewise

Case 2: if $p > q $ then $M>N $ be the exact same reason.

So $N\ne M $

Case 3: I'd $p=q $ but $r \ne s $

Then $N=qn+r\ne qn+s = pn+s =M $

So $N\ne M $.

So the only possible way for $N=M $ will be if both $q=p $ and $r=s $.

So if

$m=qn+r=q'n+r';0\le r <n;0\le r'<n$ (and $m=m $ of course), the only way this is possible is if $q=q'$ and $r=r'$.  In other words if $m=qn+r $ then $q,r $ are unique.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a different rendering of it. To show that there is only one way to write
$$
m=qn+r
$$
with $0\leq r\leq n-1$, assume it could also be written as
$$
m=q'n+r'
$$
where again $0\leq r'\leq n-1$. Our goal is to show that those two are in fact indentical, meaning $(q,r)=(q',r')$. Assume without loss of generality that $r\leq r'$. Then we have
$$
qn+r=q'n+r'\iff (q-q')n=r'-r
$$
Now since $r\leq r'$ we have $0\leq r'-r\leq n-1$. Finally, the only multiple of $n$ in this interval is $0$. Thus
$$
(q-q')n=r'-r=0
$$
showing that $q=q'$ and $r=r'$. We have proven that the two are identical.

Comment: Does ' just mean 'a unique q' ? I'm also worried about 'being allowed' to say that r $\leq$ r'. Is this where using the natural numbers is necessary?

Comment: @agra94: I did not get the first part of your comment, but yes, $r\leq r'$ corresponds to assuming $r'-r$ to be a natural number. Although in your proof we must have a strict inequality $r<r'$. I deliberately allowed them to be equal to make the proof direct instead of by contradiction. We can assume $r\leq r'$ since we are merely naming the two ways of writing $m$ in the $qn+r$ form. Why not denote the smallest $r$ and the larger by $r'$ to begin with.

Comment: @agra94: In other words, either $r$ or $r'$ will be the smallest of the two. If $r'$ is the smallest, we interchange the pairs $(q,r)$ and $(q',r')$ to have $r$ as the smallest. It is just a matter of renaming variables. The same four values $q,q',r,r'$ are still in play.

Comment: Okay. I think I'm getting there. Secondly, what do you mean by 'the only multiple of n in this interval is 0?'

Comment: @agra94: What other multiple of $n$ can you find between $0$ and $n-1$?

Answer (score 0):

We are given that

$$qn+r=q'n+r'$$ with $0\le r,r'\le n-1$.

Then by subtraction

$$|q-q'|n\le|r-r'|\le n-1.$$

The only possibility is $q-q'=0$.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my simple proof which took me way too long to figure out:

Suppose that
$$n=mq+r=mq'+r' \ ,\  q,q',r,r'\in \Bbb{Z} \\ \ 0\leq r< m \ \  , \ 0\leq r'< m $$
WLOG, suppose $q'>q$ then $$q'=q+a \ \ , \ a\in \Bbb{Z^+}$$So $$n=mq'+r'=m(q+a)+r'\\ =mq+ma+r'  \geq mq+ma\\ \geq mq+m > mq+r=n$$
Aha! It's a contradiction, thus $q'=q$ and of course proving $r'=r$ is trivial!

Explanation of the inequality chains above:

The first inequality involving $r'$ is true since $r'\geq0$ , the second one involving $ma$ is justified by the fact that $a\in \Bbb{Z^+}$ i.e. $a\geq 1$ so $ma\geq m$ , finally $r<m$ so $mq+m>mq+r$